# Python 3 File Input Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I put all my input into a file and went into the terminal to run a program getting input from a file but I got a syntax error. Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jhc6.png)

Here is the main program.

```
# Create a list of 99 Boolean elements with value False
isCovered = 99 * [False]
endOfInput = False

while not endOfInput:
    # Read numbers as a string from the console
    s = input("Enter a line of numbers separated by spaces: ")
    items = s.split()  # Extract items from the string
    lst = [eval(x) for x in items]  # Convert items to numbers

    for number in lst:
        if number == 0:
            endOfInput = True
        else:
            # Mark its corresponding element covered
            isCovered[number - 1] = True

# Check whether all numbers (1 to 99) are covered
allCovered = True  # Assume all covered initially
for i in range(99):
    if not isCovered[i]:
        allCovered = False  # Find one number not covered
        break

# Display result
if allCovered:
    print("The tickets cover all numbers")
else:
    print("The tickets don't cover all numbers")
```

Here is the input file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 0
```

Comment: Post here more details like input in file, your command and exact error that you got.

Comment: Include the text of your error, not an image file. Type it by hand if you have to.

Comment: This error is coming from `python 2` - 2 and 3 handle `input` differently. Try running your script with python 3.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 the code does not display an error. Probably the error lies in you using the input command that is different in both versions (if you use python 2, try using raw_input () instead of input ())